# How to compile kernel module together with file .s GAS Assembly

Tags: c, makefile, kernel-module, gnu-assembler

I would like to compile a file .s GAS Assembly together with my kernel module (LKM). My kernel linux version is 5.1.20-200.fc29.x86_64. This is my assembly fileasm.s:

```
 .globl  maxofthree

        .text
maxofthree:
        mov     %rdi, %rax              # result (rax) initially holds x
        cmp     %rsi, %rax              # is x less than y?
        cmovl   %rsi, %rax              # if so, set result to y
        cmp     %rdx, %rax              # is max(x,y) less than z?
        cmovl   %rdx, %rax              # if so, set result to z
        ret                             # the max will be in eax


And this is my driver.c:

#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>

int64_t maxofthree(int64_t, int64_t, int64_t);


static int __init hello_world_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Welcome \n");
        printk(KERN_INFO "This is the Simple Module\n");
        printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Inserted Successfully...\n");
        printk("%lld\n", maxofthree(10, 20,30));
    return 0;
}

void __exit hello_world_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Removed Successfully...\n");

}

module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);

EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(maxofthree);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Max");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple driver");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0");
```

In the Makefile I wrote:

```
obj-m += driver.o
driver-objs += fileasm.o

KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
        make -C $(KDIR)  M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
        make -C $(KDIR)  M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

When I try to compile I have this warning message:

```
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE()
```

And then if I try to do insmod driver.ko I receive:

```
module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

How can I do?

Comment: Your module has two source files `driver.c` and `fileasm.s`, but you want to link them together into `driver.o`. In order to do that, you will need to rename `driver.c` and list both object files in `driver-objs`. For example, rename `driver.c` to `main.c` and set `obj-m += driver.o` and `driver-objs = main.o fileasm.o`.

Comment: You're right, thank you very much. Now it's working